# page number in header next to chapter/section name

Tags: margins, koma-script, fancyhdr

I'd like to place the page number next to the chapter/section name in the white space that's not underlined (like in the `classicthesis` package (I had a look at that package but it seems like the package that's used their is deprecated)). Unfortunately my attempt doesn't realy work cos it places the page number always on the right side (even on theleft page).

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,                  
open=right,         
twoside = true,
paper=a4]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}   
\fancyhf{}                                              
\usepackage{lmodern}




\newcommand{\funnypagenumberright}{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(.1,0){{\thepage}}
    \end{picture}}

\newcommand{\funnypagenumberleft}{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
    \begin{picture}(-0.1,0)%
    \put(0,0){{\thepage}}
    \end{picture}}

\begin{document}
    \rhead{}
    \lhead{} 
    \rfoot{}
    \lfoot{} 
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark~\funnypagenumberleft}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark~\funnypagenumberright}}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd try eso-pic (http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) for this.

Comment: Yes, `classicthesis` uses the deprecated package `scrpage2`. But using `fancyhdr` is actually worse.

Comment: @Johannes_B : What's the problem with `fancyhdr` in combination with `Koma-Script` (I just replaced `subfig` with `subcaption` -- cos I just starting to write the document it's not in big issue to replace one package with another it's just I have defined some pagestyles with `fancyhdr` the need to adapted to `scrlayer-scrpage` )? But is there actually a gain in using `scrlayer-scrpage`?

Comment: `scrlayer-scrpage` *is* the package recommended for KOMA-script, it is part of KOMA-script. Look at the log-file of your document: It clearly states that using `fancyhdr` isn't recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` that is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. There you can enlarge the headwidth by `.2in` and then use `\makebox[2in][...]{\pagemark}` to print the page number.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
open=right,
twoside = true,
paper=a4]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline=:text,
  headwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth+.2in\relax:0pt
}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp~\thechapter.\enskip}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\makebox[.2in][l]{\pagemark}~\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark~\makebox[.2in][r]{\pagemark}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or with unchanged head width and `\makebox[0pt]...`:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
open=right,
twoside = true,
paper=a4]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp~\thechapter.\enskip}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\hspace{.1in}}~\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark~\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.1in}\pagemark}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you want to use `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
open=right,
twoside = true,
paper=a4]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thepage\hspace{.1in}}~\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark~\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.1in}\thepage}}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You saw the message with KOMA-Script and better not using `fancyhdr`?

With the following changes you get your wanted result:

Move `\funnypagenumberleft` to the left of `\leftmark`:

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\funnypagenumberleft~\leftmark}}
```

And change macro `\funnypagenumberleft` to (see changed numbers!):

```
\newcommand{\funnypagenumberleft}{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(-0.2,0){{\thepage}}
    \end{picture}}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,
  open=right,
  twoside=true,
  paper=a4
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{lmodern}


\newcommand{\funnypagenumberright}{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(.1,0){{\thepage}}
    \end{picture}}

\newcommand{\funnypagenumberleft}{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(-0.2,0){{\thepage}}
    \end{picture}}

\begin{document}
\rhead{}
\lhead{} 
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\funnypagenumberleft~\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark~\funnypagenumberright}}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]